# Replacing a word with trademark in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jstl-functions

I am displaying data from my oracle database onto my JSP page. Requirement is to locate “PEFC” text, remove PEFC and replace with: PEFC™

I am able to replace the word in JSTL but don't know how to put TM at the end. Here is what I have done so far which is not working

```
<c:out value="${fn:replace(pageScope.searchResultDisplay.productGroup.name,'PEFC','PEFC'+ &trade;)}" ></c:out>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve the issue by putting

> escapeXml="false"

at the end.

Comment: .. which is possibly dangerous. You might have opened the door to XSS attacks. It's better to escape the ampersand or simple add ™.